# Using Apache Poi to parse table within a table in a word document

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I was able to get the tables present in a word document using getTablesIterator() on a XWPFDocument.
But is there a way to get table within a table?

Thanks in Advance,
Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .docx "Table" doesn't directly contain other tables, but a Table Cell may do. So, you can't ask a table for its nested tables, you have to get each cell and check those.

From a XWPFTable get your XWPFTableRow instances, then from there a XWPFTableCell. You can then call [XPWFTableCell.getTables()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#getTables%28%29) to get any tables nested in that one cell.